# Jquery mobile custom icon for button phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-button

I am trying to use custom icon for my jquery mobile button. But some how It is showing only grey circle in place of the icon. other default icons are just working fine.

Following is the code for the index.html page

```
<style type="text/css">
        .ui-icon-medical-icon
        {
            background: url(images/icons-png/mfrg_18x18.png);
        }
</style>

 <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="medical-icon">Medical</a>
             <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh">Fire</a>  
             <a href="#" data-role="button">Police</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Which version of jQM? if it is 1.4, .ui-icon-medical-icon:after { background: url(images/icons-png/mfrg_18x18.png); }

Comment: Yes it jqm 1.4 . I did tried after in css but still the same result.

Comment: Here is a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/uMbpp/ seems to work fine. Is that the correct path to your image? images/ must be a subdirectory of the one the current page is in.

Comment: So i moved the images on the root folder of the index.html page and it works fine now in the browser but when I run my application on windows phone simulator it shows me a grey circle. So instead of using the image path i used the http path you gave me in the example and the icon shows in the simulator. So do i need to change some settings ? I have created png icon of 18x18 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a width and height for it.

```
   .ui-icon-medical-icon
    {
        background: url(images/icons-png/mfrg_18x18.png);
        width:18px;
        height:18px;
    }
```